# how to add windows components within VMWare

Tags: vmware

I am running Windows 7 with VMWare simulating the XP OS. I would like to add Frontpage Server Extension which is one of the windows components. So, i am going to "control panel" -> add and remove Programs->click on add/remove window components->select right component -> click install. Afterwards, windows prompts for 'windows Installation CD'. I have .iso image and also CD somewhere but how do i provide that to the VMWare? how do i install windows component in Virtual Machine?

Thank You,
Margots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the CD/DVD device added to the VMware configuration, you can simply place the CD/dvd in the drive and browse the i386 folder.  You can also select to mount the ISO from the VMware configuration rather than use a physical drive.  You can change the mounted ISO on the fly while the VM is running.

If you advise version of VMware you are using, I can likley provide more detail if needed

Comment: I am using VMWare@ Player 3.1.0 bulid - 261024. Finding CD may turn out not an easy task since i have misplaced it, so if you may help how to mount ISO would be so good. Thanks

Comment: Went into Virtual Machine->Virtual Machine Settings->Cd/DVD->selected 'Use ISO image file' and browsed to ISO file. At last, selected 'Connected' check box. Afterward OK and it works!